# Why is android.app.Activity not abstract by design?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Why is `android.app.Activity` not abstract by design if documentation/tutorials say that at least its method `onCreate()` *must* be implemented.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

> You must implement this method. The system calls this when creating
>   your activity.

Even if it was not mentioned explicitly, without the implementation there is no point in having `android.app.Activity` object, or? I understand that parrent needs probably to execute the code in own implementation of `onCreate()` but surely there can be design when part of parent `onCreate()` would a a call to an abstract call-back method which needs to be implemented by the developer.

Example of this design:

```
public abstract class Activity {


    public abstract void implementThis(Object o);

    public void onCreate(Object o){
        //Do stuff
        implementThis(o);
        //Do other stuff or end.
    }

}
```

Am I missing something here? Why is there non-abstract `Activity` if developer *must* and *needs* to subclass it and provide custom implementation?

Answer (score 4):

Read here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29

"The default implementation of this method performs a restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)."

Answer (score 3):

> Why is android.app.Activity not abstract by design if documentation/tutorials say that at least its method onCreate() MUST be implemented.

Methinks the documentation doth protest too much. You do not *have* to implement `onCreate()`. You can tell this by creating an activity without `onCreate()` and running it.

> without the implementation there is no point in having android.app.Activity object, or?

You are welcome to *carefully* set up your UI somewhere else (e.g., `onResume()`). Normally, you do so in `onCreate()`.

> I understand that parrent needs probably to execute the code in own implementation of onCreate() but surely there can be design when part of parent onCreate() would a a call to an abstract call-back method which needs to be implemented by the developer.

Sure. They chose not to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Doing your activity set up in `onCreate` is recommended but not required. Say I don't care about my activity lifecycle, I could set up everything in `onResume` and tear it down in `onPause`. Providing an abstract method called from `onCreate` is more restrictive than anything.

Note: I'm not suggesting that anyone do this - just that you **could** if you really wanted to.